# The view is not sending "input type=text" to the controller with ASP.NET Core MVC forms

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, input

I need to send from the view 3 parameters to method controller:

1. int idUsuario -> Working.
2. string respuesta1 -> debug shows "null".
3. string respuesta2 -> debug shows "null".

The first one is being send with an "asp-for". But the other ones are not being send, and are not based in "asp". Because if I declared them as "asp" are being render to view. I do not need to show the "asp" attribute model. I just need to obtain the input from view to analyze it in the method controller.

Method in my controller:

```
public IActionResult ValidarRespuestas(int idUsuario, string pregunta1, string pregunta2)
{
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <form asp-action="ValidarRespuestas">
        <div class="form-group">
            @if (Model.Pregunta1 == "1")
            {
                <label class="form-control-label">¿Cuál es su sobrenombre de la infancia?</label>
            }
            else if (Model.Pregunta1 == "2")
            {
                <label class="form-control-label">¿Cuál es el nombre de su primera mascota?</label>
            }
            else
            {
                <label class="form-control-label">¿Cuál es el nombre de la primera escuela donde estudió?</label>
            }

            <input type="text" id="respuesta1" name="respuesta1" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la respuesta a la pregunta 1">
        </div><!-- form-group -->

        <div class="form-group">
            @if (Model.Pregunta2 == "1")
            {
                <label class="form-control-label">¿Cuál es su sobrenombre de la infancia?</label>
            }
            else if (Model.Pregunta2 == "2")
            {
                <label class="form-control-label">¿Cuál es el nombre de su primera mascota?</label>
            }
            else
            {
                <label class="form-control-label">¿Cuál es el nombre de la primera escuela donde estudió?</label>
            }

            <input type="text" id="respuesta2" name="respuesta2" runat="server"  class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la respuesta a la pregunta 2">

            <input type="hidden" asp-for="IdUsuario" />
        </div><!-- form-group -->

        <div class="form-group mg-b-20"><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Autenticacion")">Regresar al inicio de sesión</a></div>

        @*<a href="@Url.Action("ValidarRespuestas","Autenticacion")"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Continuar</button></a>*@

        <input type="submit" value="Continuar" class="btn btn-block" />
    </form>
</div><!-- col-7 -->
```

I need to receive the 3 parameters on method controller. I'm receiving just the `idUsuario`.

Comment: Hi,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paramters'names in action are different from the names of inputs,try to change your action like this:

```
public IActionResult ValidarRespuestas(int idUsuario, string respuesta1, string respuesta2)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Hi. Yes. I changed that and is working. Thanks for your help! In the view, I'm using 2 inputs in which I added "asp-for=Respuesta1" and "asp-for=Respuesta2". I change the method in the controller with the names that you mention. And is working.